Unknown IC in garmin trolling motor
I have this burnt out IC in my trolling motor board. I have looked up the letters on the IC to no avail.


That is the SIR680ADP mosfet. The burnt out ones may be a different part though. Hopefully not.
You can buy them from e.g. Mouser. Do not buy these parts from Alibaba or Amazon since it'll be likely they'll be fakes and you may waste a lot of time that way. Only use major electronics part distributors - e.g. DigiKey, Mouser, Allied Electronics, Elfa Distrelec, Newark, RS Components.

The burnt ones are the ones I am looking to replace and yes, they are the same IC. I will look into that mosfet and see what I can find. I appreciate it!
